# on Windows XP, how can I remove (NOT hide) a system tray icon without closing the process?

Tags: windows-xp, batch, windows-registry, notification-area, regedit

So I leave uTorrent running on the system tray when I go to work, but every time my brother gets on the pc he closes it. So by the time I get back I've lost 7-8 hours of download. Most infuriating.

I want a way to remove the icon from the system tray, while maintaining the process running.

For self-educational purposes, I'd like to end up with something like this:

A batch file that when executed, checks whether some registry key is true or false or whatever, and depending on that it launches one or other .reg file that would have some effect on the icon. The practical consequence would be that launching the bat file would toggle the icon's existence on and off.

Any help?

(BTW, I want to be able to do this same thing with other programs, like eMule, or even the nvidia control panel icon, just for fun)

Comment: Have you considered just setting up separate user accounts for yourself and your brother?

Comment: Have you considered just telling your brother not to be a jerk and restart it when he's done needing the bandwidth?

Answer (score 5):

Well the trouble would be that all these programs would implement systray notifications (Things you know as System Tray icons) in a different manner and thus can not be universally removed. (Merely hidden)

However, for your uTorrent problem, the [boss-key](http://www.bittorrent.com/btusers/guides/bittorrent-user-manual/appendix-bittorrent-mainline-interface/preferences/general#Privacy.Boss-Key) ([wiki: what is a boss-key?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boss_key)) might be a solution for you...

Comment: I don't think boss-key solves the problem, it just invokes and loses background apps

Answer (score 4):

**To disable system tray icons on Windows XP / Vista**

[image]

> 1. Open up regedit.exe on Run box option.
> 2. Navigate down to following registry key :
>      HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer
> 3. check if the DWORD entry NoTrayItemsDisplay is already
>      available in the left panel,if
>      NoTrayItemDisplay available. Change
>      the value of NoTrayItemDisplay to
>      “1″if don’t have NoTrayItemDisplay,
>      Then create NoTrayItem display entry
>      and set the value as ” 1 “.
> 4. After completed modify or create the registr, Restart the computer then
>      you will see the effect that all
>      system icons tray will be hidden.

For Windows System timer, you can remove the system clock by right-clicking on the taskbar and choosing Properties and turn off ” show on clock ” option.

**Note:** *to restore the system tray icons, just navigate to windows registry and delete the ” NoTrayItemDisplay ” entry. Or create registry file or batch file one that enables and the other disables.*

*If you want me to tell how to create a reg or bat file for this then please leave a comment*
**EDIT**: To disable utorrent tray icon , simply open your utorrent, then go to **Options**, select **Preferences**, under **UI settings** uncheck **"Always show try icon"**

Disadvanntage: If your brother is smart enough or he finds this post while surfing in the internet , I am sure he will simply close the utorrent or any other program from the Task-Manager process list

So to workaround this you might wanna consider Disabling your task manager as well

here is how you can disable task-manager

> Hive: HKEY_CURRENT_USER Key:
>   Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
>   Name: DisableTaskMgr Type: REG_DWORD
>   Value: 1=Enablethis key, that is
>   DISABLE TaskManager Value:
>   0=Disablethis key, that is Don't
>   Disable, Enable TaskManager

Your Brother can still outsmart this by just killing the utorrent process using a batch script or something else.

According to me the possible solution would be to disable him from using your computer. This can be done by locking your system using a 3rd party software called Desktop Lock . For more information on Desktop-Lock go here http://www.toplang.com/desktoplock.htm

Comment: There are still many possible ways for your brother to close that utorrent but I have to go college now, so I have made it brief

Comment: It's good enough, i guess.
But please do put that in a batch!

Answer (score 1):

I have the same exact problem...except that both you and your brother are me.  I am constantly shutting down my utorrent cause I'm streaming or something.  What I did is, using Windows Task Scheduler, set tasks to start utorrent several times throughout the day, especially right after bedtime, and then again at like, 2 in case I stayed up too long.  That way your brother can actually get a speed boost but your downloads will still go through.

Alternatively you can make a batch file that shuts down utorrent, waits for 1 hour, and then starts it again.

Let me know if you need any help with those.  i'm not going to bother right now because you probably already solved this or moved on.